# Pandas partial match one df with another and return a code based on match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas in general.

I have two .CSVs that I've loaded into separate dataframes in pandas. The df1 contains 9 columns but I only care about the last one, 'Error Message Text' which is a text string containing details of an error. On df2, I have a column called 'short error message text' and 'error code'

The error message on df2 is a cleaned version of what could be in df1, I am trying to do a partial text match where on df1, id the error code given has a match to the short error on df2, then in a new column, give me the corresponding code that is referenced. I can't do a merge or join here since the data doesn't match exactly. Maybe some soft of fuzzy matching? I can accomplish this in excel using an index match with an array.

Below is an example of what I am looking at:

df1:
...,column9
"this is the error5 error"
"this thing broke because of usererror"
"there is a problem with the backend"

df2:
short_message,code
"error5", 1
"usererror", 2
"backend",3

Desired result:
df1:
column9
"this is the error5 error",1
"this thing broke because of usererror",2
"backend",3

If there is a match, return the code. If not, return a default value, like code 0.

Any ideas? I feel like I have searched all day and can't come up with anything.

Comment: You will get a quicker/better answer if you have a minimally reproducible question. Try to make an example datafame(s), such as `df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1, 1.5, 3.1, 3.4], [1, -3, 2, 8])), columns=['x', 'y'])` and then in Excel make a quick example of what you want, given the example dataframes, and post a screenshot of that.

Comment: In your example, the short_message codes are single worded. Are you looking for an exact match? As in, if 'error5' is in a <long error text>, then that is fine, but are you also looking for matching on 'error 5' and 'ERROR5' and 'error_5', based on the 'error5' short message?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you. I've created an MRE (please include one in your question next time):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

def get_short_code(long_message, df2: pd.DataFrame):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', long_message)
    for word in [w.lower() for w in words]:
        if word in df2['short_codes'].values:
            return word
    return "notfound"

dic1 = {
    "long_messages": ["this is long message error5", "this is long message error6", "this is long message backend",
    "this is long message something_else","this is long message" ]
}

dic2  = {
    "short_codes": ["error5", "error6", "tbackend", "something_else"],
    "codes" : ["ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4"]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dic1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dic2)

df1["short_codes"] = df1.apply(lambda row: get_short_code(row['long_messages'], df2), axis=1)
df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['short_codes','codes']],on='short_codes', how='left')
```

What is happening is here the following:
`df1` (long messages) get's a new column `df1['short_codes']`, by calling the function `get_short_codes` with the long message as parameter. This function basically creates a list of lowercase words (so no interpuction!) and checks for ecery word if it is in the list of short_codes of `df2` (the dataframe with short_codes and codes). If it finds it, then it returns that word (=short_code) otherwise it will be "notfound".
In the last line I merge the contents of `df2['codes']` with `df1`. Now you have a dataframe with the long messages, the destilled short_codes and the corresponding code from df2:

```
                         long_messages     short_codes codes
0          this is long message error5          error5  ID_1
1          this is long message error6          error6  ID_2
2         this is long message backend        notfound   NaN
3  this is long message something_else  something_else  ID_4
4                 this is long message        notfound   NaN
```